# reactjs gives me this error: TypeError: this.state.coords.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, function, dictionary

this is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class SeasonApp extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = { 
            coords:[],
            error:[],
        }
    }
    position = (location) => {
        let CoordsObj = {
            latitude: location.coords.latitude,
            longitude: location.coords.longitude,
        }
        this.setState({coords:CoordsObj})
    }
    err = (err) => {
        let errorObj = {
            error:err.message,
        }
        this.setState({error:errorObj})
    }
    getLoction = () => {
        window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.position,this.err)
    }
    render() { 
        return ( 
            <React.Fragment>
                <button onClick={this.getLoction}>Get Location</button>
                {this.state.coords.map(item => { //problem starts from here
                    return(
                        <div>
                            <h2>{item.longitude}</h2>
                        </div>
                    )
                })}
                <h1>error: {this.state.error.error}</h1>
            </React.Fragment>
         );
        }
    }
    export default SeasonApp;
```

> List item

my code works fine without map function, i don't understand the error.
i created a new array in state test:["a","b","c"] and tried map with it and it worked

Comment: You're setting `coords` to be an object, which doesn't have a map method. `this.setState({coords:CoordsObj})`

Comment: @pilchard thanks you are write

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
position = (location) => {
    let CoordsObj = {
        latitude: location.coords.latitude,
        longitude: location.coords.longitude,
    }
    this.setState({coords:CoordsObj})
}
```

Here you have made `coords` an object. It's not an array anymore so it can't be mapped. If you need it to be an array then do this:

```
position = (location) => {
    let CoordsObj = {
        latitude: location.coords.latitude,
        longitude: location.coords.longitude,
    };

    let temp_coords = [...this.state.coords];
    temp_coords.push(CoordsObj);
    this.setState({ coords: temp_coords });
};
```

Or, change the code inside your `jsx`

Answer (score 0):

Try to push the values to your array.

```js
position = (location) => {
        let CoordsObj = [{
            latitude: location.coords.latitude,
            longitude: location.coords.longitude,
        }]; //Note the array []
        this.setState({coords:CoordsObj})
    }
```